# Internet Connection Dying after some time

Tags: internet

I'm using BSNL 3G USB Datacard(BSNL is a ISP in India). After connecting to internet, while browsing in browser, the connection is dying. So after disconnecting & connecting back, it works proper for some time & the same problem repeats. But if I'm downloading any movie or some file through uTorrent, the connection is not dying. I'm experiencing this problem in Vista & also in Ubuntu. Help me with this please. Thank you.

Comment: Try some [Keep Connection Alive](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/08/31/keep-connection-alive/) [tool](http://www.freedownloadscenter.com/terms/keep-connection-alive/alive.html) it should help

Comment: Shark is likely right, it sounds as if your connection is being closed by your provider for being idle. You may be able to alter the time at your end, but a keep alive tool should help.